# MySql Query Is Not Working Giving me an error for offset

Tags: mysql

Here's my sql Query

```
 SELECT tl.* 
   FROM tbl_listing tl 
   LEFT 
   JOIN tbl_sub_category tsc 
     ON tl.subcategory = tsc.id 
  WHERE status_mode = 1 
    AND transaction_complete = 1 
    AND is_deleted != 1 
    AND tl.status IN (10,11,28,12) 
  ORDER  
     BY tl.status ASC 
 OFFSET 1
```

And here is the error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 1' at line 12
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 1' at line 1

Comment: Format your queries and you'll see the error yourself...

Comment: As an aside, to which tables do status_mode, transaction_complete, and is_deleted belong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, replacing OFFSET with LIMIT should be enough.

```
select tl.* from tbl_listing as tl left join `tbl_sub_category` as tsc on 
tl.subcategory = tsc.id where status_mode = '1' and transaction_complete = '1' and 
is_deleted != '1' and tl.status in (10,11,28,12) ORDER BY tl.status ASC LIMIT 1
```

You can use additional parameter in LIMIT like LIMIT 0, 2 to limit records starting from 0 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

offset must be used in conjunction with limit

query should be

```
select tl.* 
from tbl_listing as tl 
left join `tbl_sub_category` as tsc on tl.subcategory = tsc.id 
where status_mode = '1' 
  and transaction_complete = '1' 
  and is_deleted != '1' 
  and tl.status in (10,11,28,12) 
ORDER BY tl.status ASC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;
```